# Jenkins Pipeline building micro-services with multiple repos

Tags: docker, github, jenkins-pipeline, microservices

I'm trying to put together a Jenkins pipeline that builds a docker application composed of multiple containers.  Each service is in it's own git repository.

i.e.

- Service1  github.com/testproject/service1
- Service2  github.com/testproject/service2
- Service3  github.com/testproject/service3

I can create a Jenkinsfile that builds the individual services, but I'd like a way to build and test the application end-to-end if any single service changes (avoiding rebuilding the unchanged services).

I could maintain 3 separate Jenkinsfiles, and 3 separate pipelines to achieve this, but it seems like a lot of duplication.   Is there a way to have a single pipeline that will let me achieve this ?

Comment: Hello , can you please share your solution if you found any ?